# How to use [HttpPost] automatically at specific time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, timer

I'm new to C# ASP.NET Core.
I'm using now a form with a button that submit `[HttpPost]`.
I want a way to post `[HttpPost]` automatically at specific time on the server without clicking or opening anything.

I searched and found this code but did not work.

```
bool _ran = false; //initial setting at start up
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 11 && _ran == false)
    {
        _ran = true;

       (action to do)
    }

    if (DateTime.Now.Hour != 7 && _ran == true)
    {
        _ran = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "`i want a way to post [httppost] automatically at specific time on the server without clicking or opening anything."` What do you mean by? Did you mean auto timer for executing post request?

Comment: yes exactly auto timer for executing post request

Comment: You can either: Have a timer/scheduler in the service and call the underlying request handlers directly or if we are talking azure, you could have a timer triggered azure function, ... all of which is assuming that makes sense in the first place. What are you trying to do?

Comment: _"automatically at specific time"_ - can you specify: Does that mean "every day at 11:00 a.m. and 7:00 p.m." or more like "when an hour has passed since last call"?

Answer (score 0):

> im new to c# asp.net core im using now a form with a button that
> submit [httppost]. i want a way to post [httppost] automatically at
> specific time on the server without clicking or opening anything.

Well, you can use [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0) in order to execute anything on specific schedule basis. Periodic timer has the method called [WaitForNextTickAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0#methods) which will be waiting for next autometic execution. Basically, once its been activated, then it will be tiggered as per your next timer interval.

Apart from that, you even can do that using couple of other srevice as well. For instance [Windows Worker Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers?pivots=dotnet-7-0) or [TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-7.0). However, it would depend on your scenario and requirement. For just a simple scheduling you can have a try with PeriodicTimer but if you have specific requirement you can the try worker service.

But in general, you can have a try with PeriodicTimer. Let's have a look, how you can implement that:

```
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

int counter = 0;
while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    counter++;
    if (counter > 5) break;
    ExecutePostRequestTimer(counter).Wait();
}


static async Task ExecutePostRequestTimer(int counter)
{

    HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    UpdateAddressModel modeldata = new UpdateAddressModel();
    modeldata.Email = "kirontest@outlook.com";
    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(modeldata);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:5094/api/User/EditAddress", json);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Current counter: {0} Last Fired At: {1}, response Status: {2}", counter, DateTime.Now, response);
    
}
```

**Note:** I have tested that using console app and asp.net core API application. You can do that using your suitable app. Please [refer to this official docs for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0#methods)

Comment: I am suspecting OP needs something like a scheduler rather than something periodic. But I requested clarification on that.

Comment: Yes, sure, we can either create windows service for schedular or can even call PeriodicTimer. But yeah, still depends on the requirement. I will update the answer once again. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) as a scheduler.

For instance, this is the minimal setup in as ASP.NET Core app with an action (writing to the console) that is executed every minute (when second is zero):

`Program.cs` file:

```cs
using Quartz;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    var jobKey = new JobKey("MyJobKey");
    q.AddJob<MyJob>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));
    q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
            .ForJob(jobKey)
            .WithIdentity("MyJob-trigger")
            .WithCronSchedule("0 * * ? * *") // Use a CRON expression here. This particular one can be described as "run every minute" (when second is zero)
    );
});
builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);

WebApplication app = builder.Build();
app.Run();

class MyJob : IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow); // Do anything you need here
        return Task.FromResult(true); //Note: This method must always return a value. This is especially important for trigger listers watching job execution 
    }
}
```

Just replace the `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow)` with any real code you want executed, and update the `"0 * * ? * *"` CRON expression to do it when you want (you can use this [helper page](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) to create the CRON expression required to your needs).

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => {
    var waitFor = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(7) - DateTime.Now;
    await Task.Delay(waitFor).ConfigureAwait(false);
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    var requestJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    var content = new StringContent(requestJson, encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    await client.PostAsync(url,content).ConfigureAwait(false);
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```